# Evaluate all javascript in html to get final html document (java)

Tags: java, javascript

How can I get the 'final' html after all javascript is evaluated on a webpage. For example if you look at the page source for a simple Google search https://www.google.com/#q=books all you can really see is a bunch of javascript. But if you 'inspect element' you can see the actual html that is rendered by the javascript. I want this.

I have tried messing with HtmlUnit and JSOUP, but I just don't see how to get the final 'rendered' html. Maybe I am missing some javascript execution call?

I have tried HtmlUnit:

```
  final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
  System.out.println(page.asXml());
```

and JSOUP:

```
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
  System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

But neither seems to resolve the google.com search javascript.

EDIT: It seems like it might just be google's crazy javascripts that I am having trouble evaluating. I was able to generate dom/xml by pointing to a really simple html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("Welcome!!!");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, after the JS is applied you don't get HTML, but a DOM tree instead. A DOM tree is basically a set of nodes with attributes, so the easiest way would be to traverse it and print the nodes.

Comment: I think this is a server side plugin you are looking for. Am I correct?

Comment: I also tried doing something like this with HtmlUnit
    for (DomNode node : page.getDescendants()) {
        // System.out.println(node.toString());
        if (node instanceof HtmlScript) {
          ((HtmlScript) node).executeScriptIfNeeded();
          System.out.println("Rendered script: " + node.asText());
        }
      }
But that just seems to print the javascript out and not evaluate anything. Maybe it is something specific with the google javascript? I can try on a simpler javascript html page.

Comment: HtmlUnit seems to work fine with a simple javascript page that just does document.write("Welcome!!!"); It actually display the text as part of page.asXml() and it is part of the DOM produced... so maybe my issue is with being able to evaluate the crazy Google javascript? Browsers seem to be able to do this fine!

Comment: A headless browser will help, check this out http://phantomjs.org/ Might be useful

Answer (score 0):

Alright... so apparently HtmlUnit was working fine, except not on the google url such as https://www.google.com/#q=books but if I change the url to something like https://google.com/search?hl=en&q=books then it is able to evaluate all the javascript and produced a useful DOM.